# Wait until page is loaded, and move, wait again with Selenium WebDriver for Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium to check search results.
I want to check on the search result and move into the detail page.
So, I used the 'WebDriverWait until' twice.
It seems working well for the first wait, but it didn't work with the second wait.

when I added time.sleep(0.5), it worked.
But, I don't want to use sleep for this.

Can you guys check my script?
for the test, I already input the IP address in the script. I will change it later.

---

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe",options=options)

url='https://viz.greynoise.io/query/?gnql=103.151.125.252'

driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 7).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'grid-container.sidebar-one')))

temp=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]')

if len(temp[0].text) == 0:
    print('103.151.125.252' : X')
else:
    url='https://viz.greynoise.io/ip/103.151.125.252'
        
    driver.get(url)
    
    WebDriverWait(driver, 7).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/div[1]')))
    
    temp=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/div[1]')
    
    time.sleep(0.5)
    #It's doen't wait without sleep(0.5)
    if len(temp) == 0:
        print('Possible Scan IP with no Tags')
    else:
        print(temp[0].text)
```

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @DebanjanB I want to check the search result(https://viz.greynoise.io/query/?gnql=103.151.125.252) first and then get data from the detail page(https://viz.greynoise.io/ip/103.151.125.252)
I can get the data from the detail page, but sometimes there are no details like this URL https://viz.greynoise.io/ip/159.89.146.3

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you dont want to use time.sleep if it works, but you could also use driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)

Comment: In case it won't work well. Maybe later I have to increase the wait time.
So, I just wanted to check the element and read the data